# Which is the right workflow with DBs and Docker

Tags: database, nginx, docker, dns, docker-compose

I want to build my Docker eco system, following the best practices. I read and I consulted with some people specifically for databases and whether I need to add them by docker-composed and whether I need to link them with the container application. All they told me that this is not a good practice and app containers have to access db containers via DNS (as happens with AWS RDS for example ). The DB can be on another server and then really this is the way and I agreed with them. All that is very well, but now I have another question.

If I have 10 applications and all of them has to have a mysql database.

If I create db for each application, which is the best and **safest** way to access these dbs via DNS?

Do I use Nginx Proxy or are there other better and **secure** ways?

Answer (score 1):

The older "linking" mechanism is now deprecated in Docker. DNS resolution of container names is now built into Docker.

To resolve DBs running as containers on alternative hosts you'll need to configure a Docker Swarm.